# How do I use Reveal.js in an Express.js app?

Tags: node.js, express, reveal.js

I'm trying to figure out a way to create simple presentations from data in a SQL database. I'm looking into Reveal.js, but it seems I need to navigate to a static *.html page in order for the js framework to be fully functional. When I tested Reveal.js on an Express.js app I had, it would not fully load when the route was hit.

I would like to be able to load a presentation dynamically based on the route, so something like:
domain.com/presentation/1 (then the presentation with id of 1 loads)

Is this possible with Reveal.js, or is there another framework that would work better?

Comment: Please make clear that you just want to load dynamic pages based on router id. which you can achieve directly with express.js without using Reveal.js as well.

Comment: I want to load dynamic content based on a router id, correct. But I would like the framework of Reveal.js to create a presentation from this content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer.

I'm new to a lot of this stuff, so it is basically trial and error until something works. I was going through the error logs and noticed that the .js libraries for the presentation frameworks were posting 404 errors. I tried changing the path to the files and nothing was working. What ended up working was when I placed the .js files into the public directory.

So, now I can set a route of domain.com/presentations/:id and the :id parameter will pull a presentation from the database based on that id.

I also ended up going with present.js for the framework - not sure if that mattered.